# test GameCenter Multiplayer on emulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

are there anyways I can test a multiplayer games on the xcode emulator? because right now I am creating a multiplayer game and its my first one so there is alot of testing and it just seems like there should be an easier way to test the app rather than installing the build on 2 devices everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xcode to build and run multiple instances of your application. You can select a connected device and build&run. Then select your iPhone simulator or another connected device and use build&run again. In the console you can switch between the two instances.

Comment: thanks alot for the answer, but I couldnt find a way to run the app on my ipad by building and running it... how can I add my ipad to the list?

Comment: you have to open the Organizer in Xcode (shortcut CMD-Shift-2) and go to devices. Add your iPad as a development device. Then you should be able to build and run on it. Of course you need to be an iOS developer (costs $99/year).